# How to know direction of propagation of wave?

Tags: waves

I thought a way but don't know whether it is correct or not. Like equation of wave is $$y=A\sin(±wt±kx±\phi)$$ one way is keeping input of sine constant which visually means that we are indicating a particular position with respect to wave and we just have to find whether that position is moving left or right with change in time which is obviously positive.

So to find that out we have to find out that $x$ is increasing or decreasing with time which means that if that position is moving forward in $x$ axis or backward in $x$ axis. Actually when we see equation then there are many possible combinations of getting different signs at different positions like $y=A\sin(wt+kx+\phi)$ now sign with $\phi$ do not matter in deciding direction of propagation (nor its magnitude) because it just fixes initial phase of wave and nothing more and we can also think it like, for a particular case $\phi$ is fixed then how can it help in movement of wave because it is itself fixed.

Now consider equation $y=A\sin(wt-kx-\phi)$ analytically roughly $-\phi$ is already a constant $t$ will obviously increase so for keeping whole bracket thing constant we have to increase $x$ and believe me it can be constant because domain is real numbers. And magic we have to increase $x$ that means the position which we have choosen on wave (constant) is moving forwards and for other combinations of signs in equation we can similarly work out. Or rather we can use more mathematics to do the same which is called differentiation (with respect to time considering whole input of sine as constant) because input of sine is completely linear after differentiation if rate of change of $x$ w.r.t time $(\frac{dx}{dt})$ is positive ($x$ increasing, same story) wave is moving forwards (considering that orientation of wave with respect to you) if it is negative then opposite story.So this was not my thought purely but one of the way but tell me if this is correct approach or not.

Now my thought:- consider equation $y=A\sin(-wt-kx-\phi)$ now because $\phi$ has no role in determining direction of propagation of wave so we can take any $\phi$ to find out direction of propagation, to easily visualize the wave and case we can take $\phi$ as zero and if not taken then this way is not useful in determining direction of propagation I will tell you later why it is not useful in that case. One more thing sine or cosine also don't matter to find direction of propagation because they just have different initial phase s and overall shape of both is same and I had already explained that  do not matter.

Now we will analyze wave from $x=0$, initial phase $=0$, considering sine wave now we have to visualize wave in our mind with the given conditions (as shown in figure 1) (equation is $y=A\sin(-wt-k×0-0)=A\sin(-wt))$ now if we increase time a little bit from $0$, $y$ will come out to be negative(if $wt$ is in first or second quadrant excluding end lines of quadrant,$w>0$) this means wave has moved towards right. But this is not true actually (believe me) now where the mistake lies? We have considered the wrong shape of wave actually it should be actually upside down (as shown in figure 2) how to know the shape of wave?

Consider $t=0$ and move in $x$, in same equation, ( $=A\sin(-wt-k×0-0)=A\sin(-wt)$) increase  $x$ from $0$ (increase such that $(x\to 0^+)$ in other words increase by very little), $y$ will come out to be negative ( problem solved, as there are only two possible ways to draw sine curve or maybe not because its just change of initial phase but simply saying upside down) now you know shape of propagating wave for that equation(as shown in figure 2) and now you will find out direction of propagation correctly remember we got negative value of $y$ on increasing time and now it is justified that wave will move towards left that is correct direction of propagation (in negative $x$ direction) you can similarly figure out direction of propagation for different possibilities of sign (or permutations) in the equation.

Where this method fails is when you take initial phase such that wave is symmetric about $x$ axis (or reflection) in that case will try to increase time from $0$ and try to find change in $y$ then it will show same trend whether the wave is proceeding towards $+x$ or $-x$ direction. That's why I told you to take initial phase as $0$ because phase already do not matter.

If you want some learning technique then if signs with $wt$ and $kx$  are same then wave will move towards negative $x$ if opposite then in positive $x$ direction. Sorry for explaining like explaining to a student. Now my main question is that are the both ways correct?

[image]

Comment: If all else is constant remember that $f(x+a)$ moves a function to the right by a units for $a<0$ and to the left a units for $a>0$.

Comment: Is my explanation correct

Comment: "If all else is constant remember that f(x+a) moves a function to the right by a units for a<0 and to the left a units for a>0".  I know that

Comment: If you are saying from the ∅ story that I explained then I doesn't meant to say that

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Please answer my question

Comment: I will use it next time

Comment: All my notations are approximately correct, so why I have to use it

Comment: If you can, please edit it for me as you know how to use mathjax, only edit equations and notations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can simply set the phase of the trig function (by phase, I mean everything that is inside the trig function) to a constant (any constant, you can pick zero) and then isolate x. I mean by this, have the form $x = \ldots$. The coefficient of the t term on the right hand side will be the velocity of the wave. So the sign will tell you the direction.

Comment: I explained that in my explanation but not used term "velocity"

Comment: You had not answer my main question.

Comment: The title of the question is "how to know the propagation of the direction of a wave". My answer is general (for linear dispersion). There is no need to get into something more complicated than my answer of just four lines.

Answer (score 0):

> "one way is keeping input of sine constant which visually means that we are indicating a particular position with respect to wave "

For denoting a particular position, you keep the *x* constant. Obviously *t* can change.

> now sign with ϕ do not matter in deciding direction of propagation (nor its magnitude) because it just fixes initial phase of wave and nothing more and we can also

Sounds good. So from now on, in the analysis, leave $\phi$ out completely for convenience.

> Now consider equation y=Asin(wt−kx−ϕ) analytically ....... approach or not.

If you are going to differentiate the input of the sine w.r.t. time, you will not get any details about x. They are both separately independent variables used to describe *y*.

In fact, if you simply want to find out the sign of x, just *look at the expression* for the input to the sine!

You seem to be wanting to get an expression for *velocity* somehow and then if it is positive, to conclude that it is moving forwards (to the right).

> But this is not true actually (believe me) now where the mistake lies? We have considered the wrong shape of wave actually it should be actually upside down (as shown in figure 2) how to know the shape of wave?

What matters is not the current shape of the wave (by which you mean the value of y for a particular x) but how that shape will change in the future. The current shape of the wave can easily be changed with a suitable $\phi$. You concluded earlier that $\phi$ does not matter!

---

A simpler way is :
Take the equation $y=Asin(kx-wt)$ .

At t =0, $y=Asin(kx)$.

This is a simple sine wave. No problems.

Now, consider the random position x =0 .

$y=Asin(k0)=0$ at t =0

Now, if t is starting to increase, the expression is now

$y=Asin(-wt)$.

If you look , the input to the sine is *decreasing* as time is progressing.

This means that values from behind the y axis are getting pulled to the point x=0 as time increases. *I hope you can visualize this.*

But if values from behind the y axis are getting pulled to the front, it means that values **at** the point x=0 are pushed to the front. If you apply this to the entire wave, the values at every point are moving forwards as time is increasing. Then , the wave is said to be traveling forwards.

---

> Consider t=0 and move in x, ..............ign (or permutations) in the equation.

This exercise is pointless since you want to find the **time** evolution of the wave. Why would you even fix t=0 and then talk about the wave moving forwards/backwards in *time*?

Comment: You had not discussed that if my approach is wrong then why I am getting correct direction?

Comment: You are not able to understand what I said

Comment: Actually maybe you do not want to understand or you are not able to

Comment: Foget about everything I said, just apply your thought (which you explained in your answer) considering equation as y=Asin(-wt-kx) and explain me how you will get equation to move towards -ve x axis (same signs means travelling towards -ve x axis).? explain

Comment: Hi, I have taken y= Asin( kx-wt).  But as you say, let us take it as y=Asin(-kx-wt). I take the minus outside and make it as y=-Asin(kx+wt). I guess you might already know that if it is (Kx+wt), the wave is a left travelling wave.

Comment: Can you tell me from the equation which I had given you ,what is shape of wave for that equation at t=0 to predict shape of equation I had put t=0 then changed x to predict if y is increasing or decreasing on right side of x axis, which you are telling to be pointless try to understand, if you don't understand then I don't care

Comment: You can't prove a person to be inferior by using such irony in your statements, and that doesn't give good impression of you

Comment: By particular position I don't mean what you are assuming in that case I am not considering any coordinate axis then just fix phase of sine you will get a particular y which will be for a particular point on wave

Comment: Sine can also be represented in the form of phasor and if you fix a particular angle in phasor it will give particular projection which is y and y can be same for different angles but that does not mean we can't fix a particular position in wave by angle

Comment: I know we have to keep x constant but you are not understanding I said you to forget about axis thought it is there

Comment: Think on it not for opposing my statements and to prove sometimes but for physics give it a try

Comment: You are an Indian I also I am and indians usually have problem of considering someone inferior especially science students

Comment: Replying to the 6th comment on this thread: You are plotting the sine wave by taking t=0. After you have plotted it (whether it is increasing or decreasing), then what?

Comment: Replying to the 12th comment: These assertions are absurd and untrue. In fact science students should discuss with each other and solve problems, not trying to "consider someone inferior" , not trying to be the "greater" science student. If your aim is to do _physics_ , there is no _use_ in thinking of others as inferior or superior. Sometimes, some people have better skills than you and you learn from them and vice versa. Physics should not be used to create conflict but rather as a way to make friends with new people! Kindly stick to the physics alone and leave these arguments.